# What is the impact from choosing auc/error/logloss as eval_metric for XGBoost binary classification problems?

Tags: xgboost

How does choosing auc, error, or logloss as the eval_metric for XGBoost impact its performance? Assume data are unbalanced. How does it impact accuracy, recall, and precision?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Choosing between different evaluation matrices **doesn't** directly impact the performance. Evaluation matrices are there for the **user** to *evaluate* his model. *accuracy* is another evaluation method, and so does *precision-recall*. On the other hand, *Objective functions* **is** what impacts all those evaluation matrices

For example, if one classifier is yielding a probability of 0.7 for label 1 and 0.3 for label 0, and a different classifier is yielding a probability of 0.9 for label 1 and 0.1 for label 0 you will have a different error between them, though  both of them will classify the labels correctly.

Personally, most of the times, I use roc auc to evaluate a binary classification, and if I want to look deeper, I look at a confusion matrix.

When dealing with unbalanced data, one needs to know how much unbalanced, is it 30% - 70% ratio or 0.1% - 99.9% ratio? I've read an article talking about how precision recall is a better evaluation for highly unbalanced data.

Here some more reading material:

[*Handling highly imbalance classes and why Receiver Operating Characteristics Curve (ROC Curve) should not be used, and Precision/Recall curve should be preferred in highly imbalanced situations*](https://www.kaggle.com/lct14558/imbalanced-data-why-you-should-not-use-roc-curve)

[*ROC and precision-recall with imbalanced datasets*](https://classeval.wordpress.com/simulation-analysis/roc-and-precision-recall-with-imbalanced-datasets/)

The only way evaluation metric can impact your model accuracy (or other different eval matrices) is when using *early_stopping*. *early_stopping* decides when to stop train additional boosters according to your evaluation metric. 
*early_stopping* was designed to prevent *over-fitting*.

Comment: In other words, one should set the parameter `eval_metric` only when using `early_stopping` (or please correct me if this is wrong).